# service database file and getservbyname_r() function

Tags: c, linux

I am running into some C code that is using the getservbyname_r() function.

I found this overview of it:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r2/ic2928/index.htm?info/apis/tsgservn.htm

but I am not sure what the 'service database file' is or how it is populated.

I am running on Red Hat EL 6.  (I'm also not sure if this question should be on SuperUser)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the traditional flat-file world it's `/etc/services` or `/etc/inet/services`; typically it's part of the base system install.  It's also possible for entries to be read from NIS, LDAP etc., depending on the system's naming services configuration (`/etc/nsswitch.conf`).